# "Create React App" cannot assign to read only property "jsx" of object in tsconfig.json file

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I have recently updated a few libraries in my application including

```
"react-scripts": "4.0.0",
"typescript": "^4.8.2"
```

Now if I run anything, my application or just a test file, then I always get this error :

```
C:\dev\shape-shop-front-end\src\admin\redux\__test__\myTest.test.ts
C:\dev\shape-shop-front-end\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\utils\verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:239
      appTsConfig.compilerOptions[option] = value;
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'jsx' of object '#<Object>'
    at verifyTypeScriptSetup (C:\dev\shape-shop-front-end\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\utils\verifyTypeScriptSetup.js:239:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\dev\shape-shop-front-end\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\test.js:32:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to

```
"react-scripts": "5.0.0"
```

and this problem is gone.

See "Migrating from 4.0.x to 5.0.0" in https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases.

More information is here : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10110

It seems to have also been fixed in **react-scripts: 4.0.1**